# Firebase Authentication is working but data is not storing in relatime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Authentication is working fine but I am not able to store and retrive data from realtime database. Below is the firebase rule(I am using locked mode and Usa server) and my signup Activity class. Please help me with this thing. I am taking database refernce and giving setValue method but still its not working. I have also tried different solution given on stackoverflow flow but still no luck.

Firebase Rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  // 2022-8-22
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

SignUp Acitvity

```
class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDBRef : DatabaseReference

    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignIntoBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivitySignIntoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.edtSignUp.setOnClickListener{
            val name = binding.edtName.text.toString()
            val email  = binding.edtEmail.text.toString()
            val password = binding.edtPassword.text.toString()
            
            signUp(name, email, password)
        }
        binding.tvLogin.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
            finish()
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun signUp(name: String, email: String, password: String) {

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    addUserToDatabase(name, email, mAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
                    val intent = Intent(this@SignUpActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, "Some Error Occurred. Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()
                }
            }
    }

    private fun addUserToDatabase(name: String, email: String, uid: String) {
        mDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://chatapplication-ad542-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/").getReference()
        mDBRef.child("User").child(uid).push().setValue(User(name, email, uid))
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am using locked mode" The security rules that you shared are very much **not** using locked mode, and make all data readable and writeable by anyone in the world.

Comment: The code for writing to the database looks fine at first glance, but we're missing a lot of debugging information. You might want to try if something simpler works, like: `mDBRef.child("Test").set(true);`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Locked mode rules were different but I changed it to true after seeing a another solution on stack overflow. I tried .set(true) and still its not working. Should I create a new database in Test Mode and try? Also I tried debugging the project, there are no error everything is perfect, Authentication is working fine, Google signup working fine jut data not getting stored in database. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Also when I manually entered the data in realtime database and tried to read it, its not working for that also.

Comment: If you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)), does it show anything relevant on the line that is supposed to *write* to the database?

Comment: Yes it does but nothing is getting stored.